# Question about four digits appearing next to move

Tags: learning

[image: Picture of the number i refer to]

As new to this as you could get i think.
Could you explain the four digit numbers that appear next to what i guess you call annotations. I would either think it should go for the highest or the lowest number, but no.

Haven't been able to google the answer, lack of imagination i guess.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You haven't uploaded the picture. Edit your post by clicking *edit* ( second option, after *share* ) and upload the picture correct. Welcome to Chess SE!

Comment: I am guessing Rybka is approximating the 'rating' of the move.

Comment: Thanx for your reply.I know i forgot, but it should be up now. Then why does it not choose the best move, and or tell me to reconsider when i have chosen a bad move?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using "Lucas chess" here with Rybka. Even though Lucas chess is a real neat software, I eventually preferred the (-1 / 0 / +1) kind of representation of the evaluation. Each number next to the move is an evaluation or weight associated with the move. As you can clearly see it is considering many different moves (usually called MultiPV in UCI terms) and giving its evaluations.

Comment: Correct I am using Lucas Chess.
Where can i find software that has "(-1 / 0 / +1)" evaluation?
Just for my own clarification: In the above example Rybka is saying that d5 (1789) is the best move and d1 (1610) is the worst move? I just wonder since when i'm playing and testing a move it doesn't seem to add up.

Example: I make a move and after thinking it comes with an alternative move, this move has a lower number than my move.
Thanks for your reply!

Comment: You can use Arena GUI with any of the UCI or winboard engines which give scores in terms of pawns. Like for example a "-2" score shows that black is better by value of 2 pawns. It is also called white based scoring, where positive value indicates advantage for white. Negative value indicates advantage for black. Coming to your question- The lines it is evaluating every time you make a move may be different and hence the scores may start to differ once the move has been made.

Comment: Other good GUI include SCID vs PC, Tarrasch GUI. Enabling MultiPV option you can choose how many different "good" moves the engine evaluates.